# bash enable autocomplete for PATH names

Tags: bash, tab-completion

In bash, if I were to type `which pyth<tab>` it would autocomplete to `which python`. I have my own program, `limitcpu`, and if I type `limitcpu pyth<tab>` nothing happens.

Tab completion still works for files where I provide the path, but I would like it to work with files (programs) in the `PATH` environment variable as it does with `which`.

Comment: A similar question has been asked in [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete), it might help to look at the answers there.

Comment: You need to edit your `~/.bashrc` (follow the instruction in `cat ~/.bashrc`)

Comment: @GAD3R Thank you for the suggestion. `~/.bashrc` led me to `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` which showed exactly how tab completion works with `which`.

Answer (score 2):

The bash configuration option `complete -c <list of commands>` will allow each command in `<list of commands>` to autocomplete with other commands.

In this case, put `complete -c limitcpu` in `~/.bashrc` or any other place it can be sourced.